# How to search through array of nested objects using Javascript or Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects as follows:

```
const data = [
  {
    slug: "home",
    content_one: [],
    content_two: [
      {
        title: "Some title",
        description: 'Some description'
      }
    ],
    content_three: [
      {
        main_title: "Some title",
        content: 'Here comes some content'
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    slug: "contact",
    content_one: [
      {
        title: "Some title",
        description: 'Some description'
      }
    ],
    content_two: [],
    content_three: [],
  },
  {
    slug: "about-us",
    content_one: [],
    content_two: [],
    content_three: [],
  }
]
```

And I have an array of search terms as follows:

```
const search_terms = ['Some', 'title']
```

I want to search through the data array, and find all objects which have one of those searched terms.

The result should be as follows:

```
const res = [
    {
    slug: 'home',
    text: 'Some title',
    count: 2
  },
  {
    slug: 'contact',
    text: 'Some title',
    count: 1
  }
]
```

I'm not sure how to do that, because the properties of the nested arrays are not the same.

It needs to be something as follows:

```
let result = []
search_terms.map(term => {
    data.filter(item => {
    console.log(item)
  })
})
```

But not sure how to do that.

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/tox4dqj6/)

Any idea?

Comment: You can use `Object.keys(someObj)` to retrieve an array of keys.

Comment: I recommend using https://fusejs.io/. But you will first need to normalize your data.

Comment: This is quite complex to implement. Not only you need to search through every object's title and text, but you also need to ignore the case (uppercase/lowercase) which require regexes, which will also serve to count the number of occurrences. I am afraid you are asking us to develop the whole solution for you, not simply help you debug your code, and that's off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first find all objects with matching text using recursion and then do the count and remove duplicates.

```js
const data = [{"slug":"home","content_one":[],"content_two":[{"title":"Some title","description":"Some description"}],"content_three":[{"main_title":"Some title","content":"Here comes some content"}]},{"slug":"contact","content_one":[{"title":"Some title","description":"Some description"}],"content_two":[],"content_three":[]},{"slug":"about-us","content_one":[],"content_two":[],"content_three":[]}]
const search_terms = ['Some', 'title']

function search(data, terms, slug = '') {
  const result = [];

  if (data.slug) {
    slug = data.slug;
  }

  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    data.forEach(e => result.push(...search(e, terms, slug)))
  } else {
    let added = false;
    for (let i in data) {
      if (typeof data[i] == 'object') {
        result.push(...search(data[i], terms, slug));
      } else {
        const check = terms.some(t => data[i].toLowerCase().includes(t.toLowerCase()));
        if (check && !added) {
          result.push({
            slug,
            text: data[i]
          });
          added = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

function uniq(data) {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    const match = r.find(({ count, ...rest }) => _.isEqual(rest, e));
    if (match) match.count++
    else r.push({ ...e, count: 1 });
    return r;
  }, [])
}

const array = search(data, search_terms);
const result = uniq(array);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```